# Hibernate join/search on like

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have two tables/entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REFERRAL")
public class Referral implements Constants{
   ....

   @Column(name = "REFSRC_ZIP")
   private String REFSRC_ZIP;

   ....
}

@Table(name = "TerritoryZip")
public class Territory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "zipCode")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "Territory")
    private String territory;
}
```

They are not really related, TerritoryZip is used as a dictionary to find list of zip codes by territory. 
Referral.REFSRC_ZIP contains comma-separated list of zip codes. So when territory is provided, I need to use the list of zip codes for that territory (could be >2000) and find all Referrals where REFSRC_ZIP contains any of zip codes from that list.

In SQL I could do it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM REFERRAL JOIN TerritoryZip t ON b.REFSRC_ZIP like '%'+t.zipCode+'%'
```

But with hibernate I tried lots of things - none worked for me. JoinFormula almost worked (with a Territory field in Referral), but it creates field with formula expression all the time, even when Territory table is not joined (when territory is not provided)

P.S. Example above is simplified, the project uses PaginatedRepository with many other dynamically created predicates with QueryDSL, but I look for any idea now.

Comment: I suggest you will get better performance by creating a lookup table with one row for each territory-zip entry (each column indexed), instead of stringifying the zip codes. If you need the comma-separated version for some other reason, you can get it with string concatenation.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Sure that would be easier, but database and the app are what they are right now, and that part is not enough justification to rewrite quite a bit of code and go through PROD data re-population.